# Свежайшее или свежейшее?

Tags: орфография, словообразование

Скажите,пожалуйста, как правильно говорить: свежайшее или свежейшее? Если судить по правилам, то надо принять второй вариант, но почти все используют первый.

Answer (score 3):

По каким правилам? И -айш-, и -ейш- - суффиксы превосходной степени прилагательного. Чаще, действительно, употребляется свежайший, но орфографический словарь дает оба варианта.

Comment: Лаpf, после шипящих *__е__йший* непродуктивно. Так что "по правилам" скорее именно *__а__йший*.

Comment: А я и не говорю о правилах. Это спрашивающий утверждает. Я вообще свежейший впервые услышала. К удивлению, нашла и в словаре.

Answer (score 3):

Хороший вопрос! Процитирую итоговый вывод [этой интересной статьи](https://russkayarech.ru/ru/archive/2011-2/50-52):

> На основании материала можно констатировать, что вплоть до середины
> прошлого века существовал только редко употреблявшийся вариант
> **свежейший**. Вновь возникший вариант **свежайший**, морфонологически  незакономерный, оказался заметно употребительнее, что можно объяснить
> возросшей в это время «востребованностью» значения «очень  свежий».
>
> Образование **свежайший** впервые зафиксировано в «Орфоэпическом
> словаре русского языка» 1983 г. как допустимый вариант при основном
> **свежейший** (до этого регулярные образования на *-ейший* словари  не фиксировали, в чем можно убедиться, обратившись с «Сводному  словарю
> современной русской лексики»); рекомендация повторена в  5-м,
> исправленном и дополненном издании этого словаря (1989). Но в вышедшем
> в 1994 г. принадлежащем мне «Кратком словаре трудностей  русского
> языка» варианты даны как равноправные. А в готовящемся к выходу новом
> издании орфоэпического словаря вариант **свежайший**  предполагается
> дать в качестве основной нормы, снабдив вариант **свежейший**
> (зафиксированный у авторитетных авторов) пометой «допустимо
> устаревающее».